# access hidden field value into another jsp file

Tags: jsp

i've a hidden field value

```
<input type="hidden" id= "i1" name="h1" value="Request Recieved"/ >
```

i need the value to be read in another jsp file whose reference is mentioned in the current file.

i'm using `out.println(request.getParameter("h1"));` but its printing null..

Comment: `i need the value to be read in another jsp file whose reference is mentioned in the current file.` can you show bit of code for this statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work when you navigate to another JSP by a `<form>` which has this field embedded.

E.g. `page1.jsp`:

```
<form action="page2.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And `page2.jsp`:

```
<p>Hidden value: ${param.foo}</p>
```

That's all. It won't work when you navigate by a link `<a>` or submit *another* form where the hidden field is not included.

*(the `${param.foo}` does effectively the same as `out.print(request.getParameter("foo"))`, only in a less vintage and ugly manner. See also [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files))*